# IE9 - HTML5 MP4 playback problem: Weird color difference

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, mp4, codec

I have a really weird problem with IE9 and HTML5 Video playback. I have an .mp4 file which is supposed to blend with the background, which works perfectly in Chrome. But with playing in IE9 the video gets a slight darker shade than in the other browsers - a shade which doesn't show up when using my Flash fallback player for IE7 and IE8.

The HTML code is here:

```
<video id="banner-video-0" width="1280" height="572" autobuffer="true">
  <source src="/Media/Video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/Media/Video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="/Media/Video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

I think it might be some sort of codec issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a cause for this, i am experiencing the same problem and google is getting me nowhere

Comment: Nope, never did finda cause for it. But having worked with HTML5 video I think it might be codec-dependent. Try messing around with the codecs. If that doesn't help, GOK might be right, that it's just lousy browser implementations that cause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case Safari was the only major browser playing the MP4, to remedy the issue I passed in the JavaScript below that detects Safari and adds a class to the body

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0)
  {
      $('body').addClass('safari');
  }
```

Then in my CSS file I tweaked the background color to match the video background

```
body.safari,
.safari video,
.safari .mantle {
  background:#3b3b3b;
}
```

Comment: It's been so long now, that I'm not even sure if this would solve the problem I had back then, but it seems like the only solution to do some kind of browser detection. So choosing this as the answer, although it wasn't really the solution I've been hoping for.

Answer (score -1):

Buddy, there is always a difference of shades and css issues within browsers(If you are on IE & any other browsers) which make them different and kill us(Developers) ;)

Anywayz, try to handle the browser compatibility by adding script code to [detect browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) type and altering the shades through Javascript.

Njoy!!!

Comment: I know that there are browser issues. It's been a long time since I've seen two different browsers render a JPG differently. So that's why I'm asking about codecs.